# How to use Safe Core SDK in backend(Node.js)?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I want to use Gnosis Safe's Multisig wallet both from a web app(Next.js) and a mobile app(React Native). For this, using [Safe Core SDK](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk) on the backend and building APIs using it seems a good approach. So, after doing some research I found this [code example](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/scripts/sell.js) which shows the implementation of [OpenSea SDK](https://projectopensea.github.io/opensea-js/) with Node.js. That example basically composes the web3 provider using [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/)/[Infura](https://infura.io/)'s API key and user wallet's mnemonics. After some more research, I found this [article](https://0x.org/docs/guides/web3-provider-explained) which shows multiple ways of composing a web3 provider. Now I wrote a simple node app and tried with the [PrivateKeySubprovider](https://0x.org/docs/guides/web3-provider-explained#privatekeysubprovider) and Alchemy but got an error.

Simple `index.js` file:

```
const keythereum = require('keythereum') // library to recover users private key from keystore
const { Web3Adapter, SafeFactory } = require('@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk')
const PrivateKeyWalletSubprovider = require('@0x/subproviders').PrivateKeyWalletSubprovider // subproviders import
const RPCSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc') // subproviders import
const Web3ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine') // library to compose the web3 provider
const Web3 = require('web3')

// Getting private key
let keyObject = "<keystore>"
keyObject = JSON.parse(keyObject)
let privateKey = keythereum.recover("<password>", keyObject)
privateKey = privateKey.toString('hex')

const WALLET_ADDRESS = "<wallet address>"
const ALCHEMY_KEY = "<alchemy API key>"

// subprovider to sign the transactions
const privateKeyWalletSubprovider = new PrivateKeyWalletSubprovider(privateKey)
// subprovider to query/read blockchain
const alchemyRpcSubprovider = new RPCSubprovider({ rpcUrl: ALCHEMY_KEY })
const providerEngine = new Web3ProviderEngine()
providerEngine.addProvider(privateKeyWalletSubprovider)
providerEngine.addProvider(alchemyRpcSubprovider)
providerEngine.start() // web3 provider created

const web3Adapter = new Web3Adapter({ web3: providerEngine, signerAddress: WALLET_ADDRESS })

async function deploySafe() {
  try {
    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter: web3Adapter }) // Error happening here
    console.log('[safeFactory]: ', safeFactory)
    const owners = [WALLET_ADDRESS]
    const threshold = 1
    const safeAccountConfig = { owners, threshold }
    const safeSdk = await safeFactory.deploySafe(safeAccountConfig)
    console.log('[safeSdk]: ', safeSdk)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('[deploySafe-error]:', err)
  }
}

deploySafe()
```

Error:

```
[deploySafe-error]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChainId')
    at Web3Adapter.getChainId (C:\Home\Dev\gnosis-venly\node_modules\@gnosis.pm\safe-core-sdk\src\ethereumLibs\Web3Adapter.ts:47:26)
    at SafeFactory.init (C:\Home\Dev\gnosis-venly\node_modules\@gnosis.pm\safe-core-sdk\src\safeFactory\index.ts:76:44)
    at Function.create (C:\Home\Dev\gnosis-venly\node_modules\@gnosis.pm\safe-core-sdk\src\safeFactory\index.ts:62:26)
    at deploySafe (C:\Home\Dev\gnosis-venly\index.js:28:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Home\Dev\gnosis-venly\index.js:40:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Can someone help how to resolve this error? Also, is it right to use the safe SDK like this or what's the correct way of using SDK in backend for production setup?

Answer (score 0):

`web3-provider-engine` is a low-level ethereum provider, `safe-core-sdk` only supports providers from `web3.js` or `ether.js` which use such providers internally

Comment: Okay, so is it possible to use core SDK in the backend? I noticed this [issue](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/132) which shows usage of core SDK with node.js. So, If I create a web3 instance let's say with alchemy and then create an account using the user's private as shown in the issue then will that be fine to use in production?

Comment: it is possible, yes